# if $x^2+ax+b=0$ has an integer root, show that it divides b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't know where to start. can anyone help me please ?

if $x^2+ax+b=0$ has an integer root, show that it divides b

Comment: Do you know how roots and linear factors are connected?

Answer (score 3):

Simply move the $b$ to the other side to get $x^2+ax=-b=x(x+a)$.  Then clearly if $x$ is an integer, it will divide $-b$.  Note that both $b$ and $a$ must be assumed to be integers as well, however.

Comment: it is not said that b or a are integers.

Comment: If $b$ is not an integer, it is not very meaningful to say that an integer divides it.  It seems like this would be a necessary assumption.

Comment: @Hayden Not necessarily, see [my comment here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690679/if-x2axb-0-has-an-integer-root-show-that-it-divides-b#comment1447841_690701)

Comment: That is true, but I suppose I implicitly assumed the OP was referring to polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ and with divisibility defined with respect to the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not well posed. Take for example

$x^2 - \frac{19}{2} + 12 = (x - 8)(x - \frac{3}{2})$

This has an integer root of $8$ but $8$ does not divide $12$.

Another assumption is necessary (e.g. $a, b$ integers)

Comment: But $\,8\mid 12\,$ *is* true in the ring generated by the polynomial coefficients $= \Bbb Z[1/2],\,$ which is one natural way to interpret the statement in that case.

Comment: Yes, in that case the question does indeed make sense.

Comment: Anyone who can understand what divisibility in $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ means is unlikely to ask a question like this.

Comment: @JohnBentin The comment was not addressed to the OP. PS You need to write at-user if you want that user to be notified about your comment.

Answer (score 1):

By the Rational Root Theorem, any rational root of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ for a polynomial with integer coefficients $a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1+a_0$ satisfies the following properties:

- $q$ divides $a_n$
- $p$ divides $a_0$.

$$a_n = a_2 = 1,\\
a_0 = b.$$